# WPF MouseButtonEventArgs Timestamp value is negative?

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, mouseevent

I have some code for a WPF trigger that checks for double-clicks:

```
private void HandleButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
    {
        if (mouseEventArgs.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left &&
            (mouseEventArgs.Timestamp - _lastClick) < SystemInfo.DoubleClickTime)
        {
            this.InvokeActions(mouseEventArgs);
            _lastClick = 0; // Require 2 clicks again
        }
        else 
            _lastClick = mouseEventArgs.Timestamp;
    }
```

This has worked well until now. But today, suddenly single-clicks are invoking the action.  When I checked the code, I have found that the timestamp value is *negative* which results in it always being less than the SystemInfo.DoubleClickTime (500 is what mine is set to).

Is this normal?  Why has this suddenly changed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `InputEventArgs.Timestamp` property behaves like [`Environment.TickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.environment.tickcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), where you can find the following Remarks:

> The value of this property is derived from the system timer and is
>   stored as a 32-bit signed integer. Consequently, if the system runs
>   continuously, TickCount will increment from zero to Int32.MaxValue for
>   approximately 24.9 days, then jump to Int32.MinValue, which is a
>   negative number, then increment back to zero during the next 24.9
>   days.
>
> TickCount is different from the Ticks property, which is the number of
>   100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 1/1/0001, 12:00am.
>
> Use the DateTime.Now property to obtain the current local date and
>   time on this computer.

Ignoring the rare case when the jump occurs (after 24.9 days, then every 49.7 days), you may check like this:

```
Math.Abs(mouseEventArgs.Timestamp - _lastClick) < SystemInfo.DoubleClickTime
```